# React: Load Content from Server and Render to React

Tags: reactjs

I want to load my Forms via request into my ReactApp.
I fetch the content via fetch and than  put the content into the state to publish it as child from the component.
The example works good with normal HTML but not with html which has react components in it.

```js
class Box extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {bla: ""}

        fetch('test.php')
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(data => this.setState({ bla: data }));
        
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.bla}}></div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Box, null),
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use React.createElement
just try using

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Box/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```